# Java web service generates wrong response

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jakarta-ee

I am trying to make a web service with Jax-RS (using the Glassfish 3.1.1, all RI). 
The Question class is annotated with @XmlRootElement and have this method. I have not annotated it with any Jax-RS annotations. What I expected was that you would get one answers-element that had all the answer-elements inside...but that is not the case obviously. How do I that? The Answer class is also annotated with @XmlRootElement.

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public List<Answer> getAnswers() {
    return answers;
}
```

This is the response:

```
<questions>
<question>
    <answers>
        <correct>true</correct>
        <description>Answer one</description>
        <id>1</id>
    </answers>
    <answers>
        <correct>false</correct>
        <description>Answer two</description>
        <id>2</id>
    </answers>
    <description>Question One</description>
    <id>1</id>
    <imageName>hello.png</imageName>
    <status>SUBMITTED</status>
</question>
...
</questions>
```

Comment: Please consider showing the other classes you referenced. If the problem exists in that code, we can't help you spot it :(  Maybe also show an example of the response you're expecting.

Comment: But I already gave you the response? it is the XML.

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't clear to me what you were trying to do, as you are mentioning other classes -- like the elusive Questions class -- that you didn't list. It looks like someone was able to answer though. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The annotation you're looking for is XMLElementWrapper

```
@XMLElementWrapper("answers")
@XMLElement("answer")
private List<Answer> answers;
```

Should give you

```
<answers>
    <answer>...</answer>
    <answer>...</answer>
</answer>
```